# How do I make a UITableViewCell nib accessory work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to use an accessory on my custom UITableViewCell, but unfortunately I am not sure how to do that. I tried making an outlet but the line didn't connect anywhere (although the cell has the custom class selected).

This is the nib's header:

```
#import "UIKit/UIKit.h"

@interface CustomCreditCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *profileName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ccNumber;


@end
```

And this is the cell class:

```
#import "CustomCreditCell.h"

@interface CustomCreditCell()
@end

@implementation CustomCreditCell



@end
```

Comment: What is a "nib accessory"??? A nib doesn't have a header, so it's unclear what you're even asking. And a cell cannot have a cell as a property, so your code is insane.

Comment: @matt my code might be insane but it works. That property is the cell view, not a cell. A nib accessory is for example the small `i` icon that you press to get more information. I am trying to hook that accessory with the rest of my code.

Comment: OK, what does "hook that accessory" mean?

Comment: That accessory is a button. I'd like to attach that button to a segue to display more information about the cell. Unfortunately, because I load the cells dynamically, I am not sure how I can do that.

Comment: Sorry but it makes no sense that your `CustomCreditCell` class has a property that is an outlet of type `CustomCreditCell`. Why would a cell class have a cell property of the same type?

Comment: @rmaddy indeed it does not make any sense. It appears to be the UIView of the cell as I can change the background color with it.

Comment: A UITableViewCell is a UIView.  You shouldn't need to keep a reference to the cell within itself.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about that.

Comment: There is no button or accessory view in your code, so what are even talking about?

Comment: @matt That's the point. Storyboards is not letting me connect the button.

Comment: There is no storyboard in your question. If this is about something you are trying to do in the storyboard, not code, delete all the code from the question and post a screen shot showing what you’re trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. Found an answer for this myself.

Turns out that there's a sweet, sweet method called `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` that allows me to retrieve info in the same way as `cellForRowAtIndexPath`and possibly making a segue programmatically without touching my custom xib at all (apart from needing an accessory selected in the UITableViewCell configuration).

Answer (score 0):

In your header file you would typically put an outlet to refer to a button that you drag into your IB view hierarchy for the cell.  You could then ctrl-drag from the cell class in IB onto the button to wire up the outlet.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *infoButton;
```

You would also create an action in the cell class to receive the message when the button is clicked:

```
- (IBAction) handleInfoButtonClick: (id) sender {
    /* do click here */
}
```

and ctrl-drag from the button to the cell in IB to indicate what action the button will invoke.

For a beginner's tutorial on wiring up code to interface elements, you might refer to Apple's getting started tutorials:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html